# mongoose find() returns different _id than what stored in the collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Recently encountered something very strange when working with MongoDB.

It seems that when I query a collection for a document, it creates for the queried document a new _id and not returning the _id stored in the DB.

For example:

In my Database, I have created a collection named `user_types`. it has 2 documents:

```js
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6480989a8e96e5da4f9c8488"
  },
  "type": "User"
}, 
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6480986b8e96e5da4f9c8487"
  },
  "type": "Admin"
}
```

I have defined a Schema of `user_types` like that:

```js
const user_types_Schema = new Schema({
    type: String
}, {versionKey: false});
```

And then creating a model from it and connecting it to the user_types collection in the db:

```js
const UserType = mongoose.model('UserType', user_types_Schema, 'user_types');
```

Now, when I try to query using mongoose and the model like that:

```js
const query = await UserType({type: 'User'});
```

It returns:
`{ type: 'User', _id: new ObjectId("6492e2b6a618d51eeb7e63a9")`.

Note that the _id that returned by this query is different than what is in the db.

Am I doing something wrong ?

Is there even a way to get the original _id that is stored in the db?

Comment: Can you confirm whether `const query = await UserType.find({type: 'User'})` works for you?

Comment: @deepanshu yes it does, I have stated in the question that it does return but it returns a different _id than what's stored in the DB.

Comment: Does your query contains `find` method to query database. As your query as of now, creates a new document.

Comment: @deepanshu I just realized that I didn't write the .find(). Feel dump now hehe. Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem lies in the query that you are using.
Your query as of now is creating a new document, instead of querying the database.

So update your query to include a `find` method.

```
const query = await UserType.find({type: 'User'})
```